# A Serre-like theorem for regular spaces

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a sufficiently regular space of dimension (n), for example a PL manifold or a regular variety. Is it true that 
$$gl.dim(Sh(X)):= \max_{\mathcal{F} \text{sheaf} } \min_{I \text{inj. res.}} \text{length of } I$$
equals to $n$?

Remark 1: this is similar to Serre theorem in the sense that for a regular ring, $gl.dim(R-mod)=dim(R)$.

Remark 2: In Methods of homological Algebra, Gelfand Manin, is showed that if $F$ is flat, it has a flat soft resolution of length $n$.

Comment: The title says "manifolds" but the body says "variety." Is this a question about manifolds or about varieties?

Comment: Oh damn, you are right. I was in doubt about which kind of regularity one needs. So, i will turn it into a generical "sufficiently regular".